# How do you propose an edit that changes a tag from a synonym to a separate tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've come across [edit-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-mode). It is similar to [object-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-mode), but rather than being a separate tag, it is currently a synonym for [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing).  since *Edit Mode* is a specific mode that *Objects* can be in, it's no really the same as *editing*, which can cover editing topics other than those applying to objects.

We can discuss whether it's too late to change the tag from a synonym, and perhaps I should ask a question specifically to do that; but for this question, I'm focusing on the general case of editing synonyms.

EDIT: clarification in response to an answer.

So the question is, "*in general*, if one wanted to edit a tag that is already a synonym for an existing tag, is it possible to modify the tag wiki so they are no longer synonyms, and if it is, what is the process for the Blender StackExchange?"

Comment: The answer to your general question is that only mods can swap/delete synonym relationships. Relevant MSE post: [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/335251)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reversed the tag synonym between edit and edit-mode.

Reason being [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit) tag sounds like a meta tag to me, it is generic and tells little about what a post may be about, since technically everything you do in Blender may be considered "editing" in some form, including everything ranging from video-editing, to editing a mesh object, encompassing editing a material, texture or a node tree.

The [edit-mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-mode) tag on the other hand has its purpose and a specific concise meaning in this context. Being an actual mode in Blender you can be in, and one only certain objects can be put in, gives us an actual scope for questions relating to that mode, that may have specific key combinations, available tools, operators, or techniques.

As for editing synonym tags, I don't think you can, being synonyms and all it means that whatever you describe the target of the synonym with, should also apply seamlessly to the source, if they don't its is probably not a good synonym relationship.

If the tags were merged after creating the synonym definition then there should be no questions tagged with the synonym tag anymore, otherwise if the two coexist and there are questions with both tags, then you should be able to edit them independently, as far as I know.

Comment: Is it possible to make it so neither is a synonym of the other?  I've had an edit accepted to the [tag:object-mode] tag to make it reflect the manual and if I offer such an edit for [tag:edit-mode] now, to make it consistent, [tag:edit] would lose it's general meaning.

Comment: That was the intended outcome, the edit tag should not exist on its own, and is for all intents and purposes a synonym of edit-mode. That is my opinion at least, not sure what the rest of the community has to say about it. If someone disagrees please do voice your opinions as another answer

Comment: To be clear the edit tag doesn't really exist at the moment as a standalone tag, nor should it. It has been replaced by edit-mode, and has been merged with it, so the two are effectively one tag and edit tag can't be created again.